# Tensorflow: validation prediction outs the same for each image

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, dropout

I have the following problem.

I am trying to train a 3d CNN in tensorflow. I have separated the data in three data sets, train, validation and test.

The main problem is that when I test the validation set after 5 epoch of training the output of the model is the nearly the same for the 5 images.
(this is the output of the last layer without any softmax)

```
2018-04-17 23:30:35.134318 Prediction: [[0.8185656  2.7571523 ]                     
[0.8200048  2.7590456 ]
 [0.8185656  2.7571523 ]
 [0.8200048  2.7590458 ]
 [0.7751368  2.7532804 ]
 [0.82061136 2.7588618 ]
 [0.8130686  2.7821052 ]
 [0.83537185 2.7514493 ]
 [0.8200041  2.7590454 ]
 [0.81701267 2.7519925 ]
 [0.8424163  2.8674953 ]
 [0.82000506 2.7590454 ]
 [0.81999433 2.7590487 ]
 [0.81701267 2.7519925 ]
```

However, if i do the same for trainning set I get a conventional prediction.

I have fully check the data sets and both are correct and in the same conditions.

This is my mode used to build the model and do the training:

class Cnn3DMRI(object):

```
def weight_variable(self, shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(self, shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv3d(self, x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv3d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool3d(self, x):
    #                        size of window         movement of window
    return tf.nn.max_pool3d(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def dense_to_one_hot(self, labels_dense, num_classes):
    """Convert class labels from scalars to one-hot vectors."""
    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    return labels_one_hot


def wrapper_image(self, full_image_set, full_label_set, last_batch=0, batch_size=5):
    batch_img = full_image_set[last_batch:batch_size+last_batch, :, :, :]
    batch_label = full_label_set[last_batch:batch_size+last_batch]
    return batch_img, batch_label, batch_size+last_batch


def convolutional_neural_network(self, x, img_sz, n_slices):
    weights = {
        'W_conv1': self.weight_variable([3, 5, 5, 1, 32]),
        'W_conv2': self.weight_variable([2, 5, 5, 32, 48]),
        'W_fc': self.weight_variable(
            [
                int(
                math.ceil(
                    n_slices / 8
                ) * math.ceil(
                    img_sz / 8
                ) * math.ceil(
                    img_sz / 8
                ) *48), 2048
            ]
        ),

        'W_fc2': self.weight_variable([2048, 1024]),
        'out': self.weight_variable([1024, 2])
    }

    biases = {
        'b_conv1': self.bias_variable([32]),
        'b_conv2': self.bias_variable([48]),
        'b_fc': self.bias_variable([2048]),
        'b_fc2': self.bias_variable([1024]),
        'out': self.bias_variable([2])
    }

    self.x_im = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, n_slices, img_sz, img_sz, 1])
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(self.conv3d(self.x_im, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = tf.Print(conv1,[conv1], 'The conv1: ')
    conv1 =self.maxpool3d(conv1)
    conv1 = tf.Print(conv1,[conv1], 'The max1: ')
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(self.conv3d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv1 = tf.Print(conv2,[conv2], 'The conv2: ')
    conv2 = tf.nn.max_pool3d(conv2, ksize=[1, 4, 4, 4, 1], strides=[1, 4, 4, 4, 1], 
                             padding='SAME')
    conv2 = tf.Print(conv2,[conv2], 'The max2: ')
    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1,int(math.ceil(n_slices/8)*math.ceil(img_sz/8)*math.ceil(
        img_sz/8))*48])
    fc = tf.Print(fc,[fc], 'The reshape: ')

    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
    fc2 = tf.Print(fc2,[fc2], 'The fc: ')
    dp1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2, self.keep_prob)

    fc3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(dp1, weights['W_fc2'])+biases['b_fc2'])
    fc3 = tf.Print(fc3,[fc3], 'The fc2: ')
    dp2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc3, self.keep_prob)
    output = tf.matmul(dp2, weights['out'])+biases['out']
    output = tf.Print(output,[output], 'The output: ')
    return output

def test_validation_set(self, sess, data_validation, label_validation, valid_batch_size=60):

    batch_img, batch_label, last_batch = self.wrapper_image(
        data_validation, label_validation, self.last_valid_batch, valid_batch_size
    )


    batch_label = self.dense_to_one_hot(
        np.array(batch_label, dtype=np.int),2
        ).astype(np.float32)


    if last_batch+valid_batch_size < len(label_validation):
        self.last_valid_batch = last_batch
    else:
        self.last_valid_batch = 0

    pred, c, validation_accuracy = sess.run(
        [self.prediction, self.cost, self.accuracy], feed_dict={
            self.x: batch_img, self.y_: batch_label, self.keep_prob: 1.0
        }
    )


    self.log("Prediction: "+str(pred))
    self.log("Label: "+str(batch_label))

    self.log("Validation accuracy: "+str(validation_accuracy))
    self.log("Validation cost: "+str(c))
    return validation_accuracy, c


def train_neural_network(self, data_img, labels,  data_validation, label_validation,
                         batch_size, img_sz, n_slices, last_batch,
                         keep_rate, model_path):

    self.prediction = self.convolutional_neural_network(self.x, img_sz, n_slices)
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y_,
                                                                  logits=self.prediction))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.cost)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.prediction, 1), tf.argmax(self.y_, 1))
    self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    hm_epochs = 1000
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_loss_mean = []
    n_epoch = 0
    learning_rate = 1e-4
    self.last_valid_batch = 0
    min_valid_cost = 0
    all_valid_cost = []
    model_path_train = 'model_train/my_model.ckpt'

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        if model_path:
            pass
            #saver.restore(sess, model_path_train)
        while n_epoch < hm_epochs:
            if len(data_img)>last_batch+batch_size:
                with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                    #batch_img, batch_label, last_batch = self.get_image(
                    #    data_img, labels, last_batch, batch_size, img_sz, n_slices
                    #)
                    batch_img, batch_label, last_batch = self.wrapper_image(data_img, labels, last_batch, batch_size)

                print "Batch label images: "+str(batch_label)
                batch_label = self.dense_to_one_hot(np.array(batch_label, dtype=np.int),
                                                    2).astype(np.float32)
            else:
                with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                    restbatch = last_batch + batch_size - len(data_img)

                    batch_img = np.concatenate((
                        self.wrapper_image(data_img, labels, last_batch, len(data_img) -
                                           last_batch)[0],
                        self.wrapper_image(data_img, labels, last_batch, len(data_img) -
                                           last_batch)[0]
                    ))

                    batch_label = np.concatenate((
                        self.wrapper_image(data_img, labels, last_batch, len(data_img) -
                                           last_batch)[1],
                        self.wrapper_image(data_img, labels, last_batch, len(data_img) -
                                           last_batch)[1]
                    ))

                batch_label = self.dense_to_one_hot(np.array(batch_label, dtype=np.int),
                                                    2).astype(
                np.float32)
                last_batch = restbatch

                ####### at the end of EACH EPOCH ###
                epoch_loss_mean.append(epoch_loss)
                print "epoch loss mean: "+str(epoch_loss_mean)
                epoch_loss = 0
                n_epoch += 1
                print "n_epoch: "+str(n_epoch)
                if model_path:
                    saver.save(sess, model_path_train)

                if not n_epoch % 5:
                    valid_accuracy, valid_cost = self.test_validation_set(sess,data_validation,
                                                           label_validation, 60)
                    if valid_cost < min_valid_cost - 2:
                        min_valid_cost = valid_cost
                        if model_path:
                            saver.save(sess, model_path)
                    all_valid_cost.append(valid_cost)
                    print all_valid_cost

                if self.last_valid_batch == 0:
                    self.shufle_data(data_validation, label_validation)

                train_accuracy = self.accuracy.eval(
                    feed_dict={self.x: batch_img, self.y_: batch_label, self.keep_prob: 1.0})
                print "trainning accuracy: " + str(train_accuracy)

                self.shufle_data(data_img, labels)

            _, c, pred = sess.run(
                [optimizer, self.cost,], feed_dict={
                    self.x: batch_img, self.y_: batch_label, self.keep_prob: keep_rate,
                    self.learning_rate: learning_rate
                }
            )

            print 'epoch_loss: '+str(c)



def main(self, data_dir, labels_dir, img_sz, n_slices, batch_size=5, last_batch=0, train=False,
         model_path=None, keep_rate=0.5):
    """

    Args:
        data_dir(list): directories of the image to be tested
        labels_dir: (str): directory of the csv file where the image are labeled, the index
        colum is the number 2 and the labels header is 'Diag'.
        img_sz: the spatial image size the be transformed to. that is the sizes with which
        the image will be trainned. width and hight must be the same
        n_slices: the number of slices for the image to be trained
        last_batch: the batch at which you want to start the trainning
        train: boolean to set trainning: 0 or testing :1
        model_path: the path where the model is saved, if there is no previous model you can
        set a path here to start a new one.
        keep_rate: the keep_probability of firing a node by means of dropout

    Returns:

    """


    self.train = train
    data_path_trainning, label_trainning, data_path_validation, label_validation, \
    data_testing, label_testing = self.load_dataset(data_dir, labels_dir,)

    data_trainning, label_trainning_final = self.load_image(data_path_trainning,
                                                            label_trainning, img_sz, n_slices
                                                            )

    data_validation, label_validation_final = self.load_image(
        data_path_validation, label_validation, img_sz, n_slices
    )


    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_slices, img_sz, img_sz]) #batch_size,
    # image_Size
    self.y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3]) #batch_size, label_size
    self.learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    self.keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    if train:
        self.train_neural_network(data_trainning, label_trainning_final, data_validation,
                                  label_validation_final, batch_size, img_sz, n_slices,
                                  last_batch, keep_rate, model_path
                                  )
```

I have already tried tf.set_random_seed( 1 )  but no correction is seen

Do anyone have any idea about, please?

thanks so much

EDITED 22/04/18:

The data to be classified are 3d images of 150x150x40 pixels in a biclass problem. I have a total 400 images approaximatly half of each class. I have separated the dataset in train (75%), validation (10%) and test(15%)

Edit2: 
I have simplified a bit my model. see up

Also mention that we have only 2 classes

I have tried another check I have train my model with only 20 images. To see if 0 cost is obtained.

result after 125 epochs:

2018-04-24 23:58:24.992421 epoch loss mean: [4549.9554141853, 1854.6537470817566, 817.4076923541704, 686.8368729054928, 687.7348744268759, 704.946801304817, 483.6952783479355, 260.2293045549304, 272.66821688037817, 116.57515235748815, 97.86094704543848, 90.43152131629176, 132.54018089070996, 69.62595339218387, 57.412255316681694, 79.66184640157735, 70.99515068903565, 55.75798599421978, 44.14403077028692, 38.901107819750905, 49.75594720244408, 52.6321079954505, 37.70595762133598, 42.07099115010351, 29.01994925737381, 28.365123450756073, 31.93120799213648, 43.9855432882905, 33.242121398448944, 36.57513061538339, 28.828659534454346, 29.847569406032562, 24.078316539525986, 31.630925316363573, 30.5430103354156, 26.18060240149498, 32.86780231446028, 25.42889341711998, 29.355055704712868, 26.269534677267075, 24.921810917556286, 27.15281054377556, 27.343381822109222, 24.293660208582878, 28.212179094552994, 25.07626649737358, 21.650991335511208, 25.7527906447649, 23.42476052045822, 28.350880563259125, 22.57907184958458, 21.601420983672142, 25.28128480911255, 25.550641894340515, 22.444457232952118, 27.660063683986664, 21.863914296031, 25.722180172801018, 24.00674758851528, 21.46472266316414, 26.599679857492447, 23.52132275700569, 26.1786640137434, 24.842691332101822, 25.263965144753456, 22.730938494205475, 22.787407517433167, 23.58866274356842, 25.351682364940643, 23.85272353887558, 23.884423837065697, 24.685379207134247, 22.55106496810913, 25.993630707263947, 21.967322662472725, 22.651918083429337, 21.91003155708313, 23.782021015882492, 21.567724645137787, 22.130879193544388, 21.33636975288391, 25.624440014362335, 23.26347705721855, 22.370914071798325, 22.614411562681198, 24.962509214878082, 22.121410965919495, 20.644148647785187, 24.472172617912292, 21.622991144657135, 21.719978988170624, 21.72349101305008, 21.729621797800064, 22.090826153755188, 21.44688707590103, 22.34817299246788, 22.93226248025894, 22.63547444343567, 22.1306095123291, 22.16277289390564, 22.83771103620529, 24.171751350164413, 22.025538682937622, 21.339059710502625, 22.169043481349945, 24.614955246448517, 22.83159503340721, 21.43451902270317, 21.54544973373413, 22.889380514621735, 24.168621599674225, 21.947510302066803, 22.30243694782257, 22.381454586982727, 22.50485634803772, 22.61657750606537, 22.288170099258423, 21.30070123076439, 22.489792048931122, 21.885000944137573, 21.343613982200623, 23.04211688041687, 24.00969059765339, 21.8588485121727, 22.199619591236115]
2018-04-24 23:58:24.992694 n_epoch: 125

the print output of each layer:

The conv1: [[[[[0.0981627107 0.100793235 0.0934509188]]]]...]

The max1: [[[[[0.102978 0.107030481 0.0977560952]]]]...]

The max2: [[[[[0 0 0.00116439909]]]]...]

The reshape: [[0 0 0.00116439909]...]

The fc: [[0.01167579 0.182256863 0.107154548]...]

The fc2: [[0.773868561 0.364259362 0]...]

The output: [[0.16590938 -0.255491495][0.16590938]...]

The conv1: [[[[[0.0981602222 0.100800745 0.0934513509]]]]...]

The max1: [[[[[0.102975294 0.107038349 0.0977560282]]]]...]

The max2: [[[[[0 0 0.000874094665]]]]...]

The reshape: [[0 0 0.000874094665]...]

The fc: [[0.0117974132 0.182980478 0.106876813]...]

The fc2: [[0.774896204 0.36372292 0]...]

The output: [[0.129838273 -0.210624188][0.129838273]...]

Shouldn't be 125 epochs enoght to overfit 60 samples?

Any idea about what is happening?

Comment: Nothing quick comes to mind. Maybe you can try printing the outputs of each layer starting from the input image all the way to final output and see where the it becomes the same. Alternatively, it would help if you could reduce the code size/complexity that still reproduces it. Maybe somebody can spot the issue.

Comment: Thanks iga for youw answer. I have reduce the number of kernels of each weight(W).  The model continue predicting the same output for each image in a validation batch. The result is different for  each validation step, but each  image in the validation step  predicts the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment that did not fit into the comment limit.

As I said before, I can't see anything obviously wrong. You might have to do some debugging. If the pre-softmax outputs are exactly the same, it is probably a bug somewhere and you can find it by finding the exact place where your presumably different inputs lead to the same layer outputs.

If pre-softmax outputs are close, but not exactly the same, most likely you have a classic issue of over-fitting. You mentioned that you have just 300 training examples - that is extremely few to train the whole net on (without using some pre-trained weights). Your net just "memorized" 300 training examples and does not generalize to validation set at all.

EDIT 04/23/18:
So, the issue is not just in validation? I interpreted your "if i do the same for trainning set I get a conventional prediction." to mean that training images are classified just fine. If you get the same prediction for your training images, most likely the data or loss or prediction calculation is wrong. I did not spot anything and guess you will need to debug. You might find "eager execution" useful for this - https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager. If you organize your model as in examples (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/3f4662e7ca8724f760db4a5ea6e241c99e66e588/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples), you should be able to use the same code with regular tensorflow graph execution.

Comment: Dear iga, thanks again for your help. Regarding ovefiting, i have printed the out of the last layer, just before softmax and it outputs not exactly the same value but really close, as it is seen in the post. I do not know  to much about CNN, altought i sound strange that after only 5 epochs the net becomes overfited

Comment: It is also strange to expect to train reasonably sized CNN from scratch with 300 examples.

Comment: Ok i will try with data augmentation techniques to see if i can get more images. Do you think that the number of weight filters could be adecuated? thanks you so much iga for your supporting

Comment: I don't have much experience working with small datasets to comment on number of layers. However, besides data augmentation you should try using some pretrained net. Regular practice is to train only the last layer, but if your images are very different from regular photos, you can try using only the first couple of pre-trained layers that extract very general features. Also, setting `keep_prob` to something fairly low (less than 0.5) might help a bit.

Comment: I have updated my description adding the result of  extra test done over my moder, could you see any clue, thanks so much for your support.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Different optimizers with different parameters (learning rate, batch size, momentum parameters, etc) are able to overfit to different extends. I would bet that if you took something as powerful as KFAC and tuned its params for a while, you will be able to achieve near-zero training loss on quite a few training examples.

Comment: May be the case that the net becomes dead becouse of Relu?, I mean that the output of a layer is projected at the left of the ReLu plot and the gradient of the function becomes 0?

Comment: I have been searching for KFAC, altoght it sems that it has not registration for 3dcnn, has it? thanks

Comment: That is also possible. KFAC can be found here - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/kfac and you are right that it is not as easy to use as regular optimizers. On a side note, this question is becoming a chat room. We should stop.